# How to determine if an array has consecutive integers and if so, how many?

Tags: arrays, scala

I am still pretty new at Scala, but I am trying to determine if an array has any consecutive integers, and if it does then how many does it have. Here is what I have so far, but I haven't got it working yet.

```
def isConsecutive(seq: Array[Int]): (Boolean, Int) = {
    var arr: Array[Int] = Array[Int]()
    for((v, i) <- seq.zipWithIndex) {
      if (i < seq.length()) {
        if (v + 1 == seq(i + 1)) {
          arr = arr :+ v
        }
      }
    }
    var res = if (arr.length() < 1) true else false
    return (res, arr.length())
  }
```

I just want to return a Boolean for whether or not the array has consecutive integers, i.e. 1,2,3, and the number of consecutive integers or zero.

Comment: How many consecutive integers would you say are contained in `Array(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10)` ?

Comment: @m-z good question. The use case for this function will only have 5 numbers in it. Really with a situation like that I'd want to get the larger set of consecutive numbers. So the output would be `true, 3`. Maybe this isn't the way to go about what I am aiming to accomplish

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def isConsecutive(seq: Array[Int]): (Boolean, Int) = {
  val count = seq.sliding(2).count(a => a(0)+1 == a(1)) 
  (count > 0, count)
}
```

And to test it:

```
scala> isConsecutive(Array(3,5,8,99))
res0: (Boolean, Int) = (false,0)

scala> isConsecutive(Array(3,4,5,8,99))
res1: (Boolean, Int) = (true,2)

scala> isConsecutive(Array(3,4,5,98,99))
res2: (Boolean, Int) = (true,3)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to check for integers that always start with 1, and always from the first element:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,8,9).zipWithIndex.takeWhile(x => x._1 == x._2 + 1).size
res45: Int = 5
```

*you can use `res45 == 0` to check your condition, no need for additional `Boolean`

Or if you want all counts of elements in any subsequences that has consecutive integers:

```
case class Counter(v: Int, counters: List[Int], prevElem: Int)   

def conseq(l: List[Int]) = {
   val r = l.tail.foldLeft(Counter(0,List.empty,l.head)){(acc, el) =>
      if (el - acc.prevElem == 1) Counter(acc.v + 1, acc.counters, el) 
      else if (acc.v == 0) acc.copy(prevElem = el)
      else Counter(0, acc.v + 1 :: acc.counters, el)
   }
   r.counters.reverse ++ List(r.v).filter(0!=)//linear time; you might consider Vector or something instead of List
}

scala> conseq(List(1,2,3,4,100,105,106,107))
res44: List[Int] = List(4, 3)
```

You can also collect intitial values (like 1 and 105 in prev example) and their indicies (like 0 and  5 in prev example) per subsequence - you can do it inside Counter as well.

Comment: Perhaps you could include definition of `Counter`?

Answer (score 1):

The following solution will try to identify the **longest stretch of consecutive integers** not just how many consecutive pairs exists. For the latter problem, the solution from @jwvh is awesome.

The idea is to have a `Result` type which you foldLeft and update accordingly:

```
case class Result(prev: Int, curMax: Int = 0, max: Int = 0) {
   /* process takes the next int and updates the result up to that point */
   def process(n: Int) = {
      val newRunningMax = if(n==(prev+1)) curMax + 1 else 0
      Result(n, newRunningMax, Math.max(max, newRunningMax))
   }
}

def findLongestConsecutiveSeq(data: Array[Int]): (Boolean, Int) = {
   require(data.nonEmpty, "Only works with non empty arrays") 
   val res = data.tail.foldLeft(Result(data.head))( (p,n) => p.process(n) )   
   if(res.max > 0) (true, res.max + 1) // max = consecutive pairs (+1 for length)
   else (false, 0) 
}
```

Testing in the REPL:

```
findLongestConsecutiveSeq(Array(1,2,3,4,5,8,9))
res1: (Boolean, Int) = (true, 5)

findLongestConsecutiveSeq(Array(1,3,3,4,5,8,9))
res2: (Boolean, Int) = (true, 3)

findLongestConsecutiveSeq(Array(3,2,2,2))
res3: (Boolean, Int) = (false, 0)

findLongestConsecutiveSeq(Array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13))
res4: (Boolean, Int) = (true, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Measure length of the longest stretch of consecutive integers, similar to current answers, but as simple tail recursive implementation:

```
  def countConsecutive(s: Seq[Int]) = {
    @tailrec
    def countConsecutiveRecurse(maxLen: Int, s: Seq[Int], currLen: Int, currVal: Int): Int = s match {
      case Seq() => maxLen max currLen
      case head +: tail =>
        if (head == currVal + 1) countConsecutiveRecurse(maxLen, tail, currLen + 1, head)
        else countConsecutiveRecurse(maxLen max currLen, tail, 1, head)
    }

    countConsecutiveRecurse(0, s, 0, 0)
  }
```